# Pandas - Replace outliers on on groupby with largest and lowest value in interquartile range in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm trying to replace outliers on a groupby basis. If it is an outlier above the range for a particular groupby it should be set to 1.5 * interquartile range + quartile 3 and if it's below the range it should be set to quartile 1 - 1.5 * interquartile range. So let's say in the image below let's ignore row with index 6 because it's null for `temperature` and `windspeed`, but let's say we group by `event` and let's say the median for snow is 20 and upper bound for determining if it's an outlier is 24, then we should set row with id=2 to 24, because `temperature` is 28, which is an outlier.

[image]

Comment: "Please post your input data as text, not image", is usually the comment you get, for this kind of question formatting. What is the good reason for posting as image here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below derives an upper and lower temperature threshold for each group, and then clips temperatures (`clipped_temperature` column) that fall outside the thresholds for their group. In this synthetic data, the first and last temperatures are extreme values, and they get clipped in the process.

```
#Synthetic 2-week data. The first and last temperatures are outliers, and will be clipped.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['m', 'tu', 'w', 'th', 'fr', 'sa', 'su'] * 2,
    'event': ['rain', 'rain', 'rain', 'snow', 'snow', 'snow', 'rain'] * 2,
    'temperature': [50] + ([30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29] * 2)[1:-1] + [-10],
    'windspeed': [6, 7, 2, 7, 4, 3, 5] * 2
})

#Group by event, and within each group drive and upper/lower temperature threshold
#Upper temperature threshold
df['upper_threshold'] = df[['event', 'temperature']].groupby('event').transform(
    lambda group: 1.5 * (group.quantile(0.75) - group.quantile(0.25)) + group.quantile(0.75)
)

#Lower temperature threshold
df['lower_threshold'] = df[['event', 'temperature']].groupby('event').transform(
    lambda group: 1 - 1.5 * (group.quantile(0.75) - group.quantile(0.25))
)

#Clip temperatures that fall beyond the threshold for their group
df['clipped_temperature'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (x.upper_threshold
               if (x.temperature > x.upper_threshold)
               else (x.lower_threshold
                     if (x.temperature < x.lower_threshold)
                     else x.temperature)
               ),
               axis=1
)
```

These are the original and resulting dataframes:

[image: results screenshot]

I suggest inspecting results using your own data in order to confirm expected behaviour and appropriate values if using the code above.